# Manually adding entries to OssLicensesMenuActivity using oss-licenses plugin with Android

Tags: android, maven, license-maven-plugin

I'm using the oss-licenses plugin ([Android - Including Open Source Notices](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource)) for my Android app to gather the license information from all the open source repositories being used.

But some publishers have not included the `<licenses>` tag in their repository's POM file. This is why the plugin won't find the license file and these libraries are missing when using `OssLicensesMenuActivity` to display the listing.

Is there a way to enter additional entries for `OssLicensesMenuActivity`?

Comment: Hi ! did you find a solution for this issue ?

Comment: No, I ended up asking the publisher to add the proper licenses tag and he did.

Answer (score 0):

There is still no easy way to do this. However, there is an open [merge request](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/pull/185) that would add this feature.

Anyway, I solved it with a workaround. First, create an empty library and publish it to your local maven(or some other maven repo), and then add the library as a dependency.
You can publish the library to the local maven repo using [this plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).

The gradle file of the library would look like this:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        release(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = "com.stephan"
            artifactId = "mylib"
            version = "1.0.0"

            pom {
                name = 'The name I want to show in the list'
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name = 'The license'
                        url = 'https://url.to.license'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the command to publish to the local maven repo: `./gradlew :nameoflibmodule:publishToMavenLocal`

In the app project this can be easily added as a dependency with the usual `implementation 'com.stephan:mylib:1.0.0'` (also add `mavenLocal()` to the repositories in the build file)

The library can be empty, the only important part is that there is a pom file containing a [`<licenses>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Licenses) element. This can be verified by looking into the local maven repo at `$USER_HOME/.m2/repositories/`

For my example this would be `$USER_HOME/.m2/repository/com/stephan/mylib/1.0.0/mylib-1.0.0.pom`